# Character spacing for "1" in a textview

Tags: android, string, textview, android-typeface

I'm using a Digital-7 Typeface for a pair of TextViews. The problem with the TextViews is that whenever I use the character "1" in it, the characters left of the "1" get pushed back and they lose their proper spacing. As seen here:

[image: ActionBar]

You can see the 9's are properly in place while the 1's get squished together. Is there any piece of code that can help me fix this or do I need a better Typeface?

Comment: Change font. Use a font which draws the "off" segments too. Or use a **monospace** font (fixed width).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what Der Golem said, switching to a monospace Typeface fixed my issue.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this property in XML, Hope it will work.

```
android:textScaleX="1.2"
```

Must be a floating point value, such as "1.2". You can change the value depending on your requirement.

Comment: Could you explain why you think this will solve the problem ? As I understand it, this will change the scale for all characters, which would actually make things worse.